# BiBTeX - citations fail

Tags: bibtex, citing, cite-package

I placed my bibliography just before the end of the file.

```
\bibliography{mybib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

@article{damodaran2010comatose,
  title = {Comatose Markets: What if Liquidity is Not the Norm?},
  author = {Damodaran, Aswath},
  journal = {Available at SSRN 1729408},
  year = {2010},
}
```

At the top, I am using the package `cite`

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

However, when I place a citation in the text, it just displays `[?]`.
Also, the article data is displayed in plain text at the end.

How can I make the citations work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run BibTeX? Note also that `@article{...}` should be in a separate file called `mybib.bib` (the name is the argument to `\bibliography`, not part of the main document.

Answer (score 3):

In your code snippet there are some errors.

For example the second `{}` in `\bibliography{mybib}{}` can be removed.
Your bib entries for your bibliography should be in a separate file with extension `.bib`.

In the following MWE I used the package `filecontents` in order to include an example bib file into my MWE.  You do not need it, just use your existing bib file (you will soon have it ;-)). In the MWE the resulting bib file has the name of your tex file, but extension `.bib`.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@book{test,
  editor    = {First Editor and Second Editor2 and Third Editor3},
  title     = {Test to show the effect},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year      = {2015},
  ISBN      = {0-0000-000000-0},
}
@article{damodaran2010comatose,
  title   = {Comatose Markets: What if Liquidity is Not the Norm?},
  author  = {Damodaran, Aswath},
  journal = {Journal name},
  year    = {2010},
  note    = {Available at SSRN 1729408},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <=== calls bib file created with filecontents!

\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image: bibliography]

Calling the package `cite` is left for homework.

BTW: the command `\nocite{*}` shows all bib entries in your bibliography (nice to check the bib file for errors).

You have to run first `pdflatex mwe.tex` , then `bibtex mwe`, then twice `pdflatex mwe.tex` (assume my mwe is called `mwe.tex`).